# What do this arrows mean? MVC Diagram

Tags: model-view-controller, relationship, diagram, class-diagram

I made this MVC diagram based on an image I found just for representation. But now I'm asked about what do the dahsed and solid arrows mean and I have no idea... can some kind soul help me? Thanks!

I found that the dashed arrows mean dependency but in a overall view I'm not able to describe what this image real means.

[MVC Diagram Image in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSLUW.jpg)

Comment: The arrows have to do with who talks to whom in the MVC paradigm.  MVC is about breaking up a program into various packages and classes to handle an event driven application.  There are many articles about it.  I suggest you do a web search for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the legend of the arrows in these diagrams (MVC - MVP - MVVM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725042/what-is-the-legend-of-the-arrows-in-these-diagrams-mvc-mvp-mvvm)